# How to prevent the screen of the iPhone to be reversed

Tags: ios, xcode

My iPhone application screen looks like this:

[image]

When i reverse my iPhone 45 degree, all the component would be messy, the search bar, the Map, etc. The weird thing is that another screen in the same app doesn't reverse when i reverse the iPhone, so this issue i had only with this screen. Is there any way to prevent the screen from being reversed when the user reverse his iPhone?

**EDIT:**

In my info.plist file, the only parameter in the array is the portrait mode:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to landscape / portrait mode? If you don't want your application to support landscape mode, you should define that in your info.plist file. For any specific view controllers you do not wish to support landscape, just implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method, like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanx for your reply, where can i find that key, i have looked in the info.plist file but i didn't find a key referring to the Landscape mode.

Comment: It is an array called "Supported interface orientations"

Comment: Please take a look on my Update, the only value in that array is the portrait mode, so why the landscape mode is still working? thanx in advance:)

Comment: This does not change functionality for the whole app, only for launch. You will have to implement the above method in your root view controller anyways.